# How to set multiple alarms in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alarms

so I'm new to coding and I'm making an app for Muslims prayer times and I want an alarms to be set repeatedly on these times 
I tried to many things but It doesn't works!

I have a praytimes class and if anyone wants it I'll put it

I will be more thankful, if you could help me on how to set an alarm for 1 prayer so I could do the rest.

**Main Activity**

```
    val latitude = 30.354802
    val longitude = 42.2461069
    val timezonoffset = 3.0
    val timeZoneId = "Middle East/Alowiqila"
    val prayTimes = PrayTimes()
    prayTimes.timeFormat = prayTimes.time12//
    prayTimes.calcMethod = prayTimes.makkah// Muslim World League (MWL)
    prayTimes.asrJuristic = prayTimes.hanafi// Shafii (standard)
    prayTimes.adjustHighLats = prayTimes.angleBased
    val offsets = intArrayOf(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) // {Fajr,Sunrise,Dhuhr,Asr,Sunset,Maghrib,Isha}
    prayTimes.tune(offsets)
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneId))
    cal.time = Date()
    val times = prayTimes.getPrayerTimes(cal, latitude, longitude, timezonoffset)
    println("prayer times for Alowiqila")
    System.out.println("Fajr : " + times.get(0))
    System.out.println("Sunrise : " + times.get(1))
    System.out.println("Duhr : " + times.get(2))
    System.out.println("Asr : " + times.get(3))
    System.out.println("Sunset : " + times.get(4))
    System.out.println("Magrib : " + times.get(5))
    System.out.println("Isha : " + times.get(6))


   // I want the Alarm to be set to the code above it

    fun startAlarm(isNotification:Boolean, isRepeat:Boolean) {
        val manager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val myIntent= Intent(this@MainActivity, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
        val pendingIntent:PendingIntent
        // SET TIME HERE
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 20)
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent, 0)
        if (!isRepeat)
            manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 3000, pendingIntent)
        else
            manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent)
    }
```

**AlarmReceiver.kt**

and here is my alarm receiver in witch I've added me notifications

```
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context)

    val myIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        context,
        0,
        myIntent,
        FLAG_ONE_SHOT
    )

    builder.setAutoCancel(true)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setContentTitle("موعد الاذان")
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS or Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
        .setContentInfo("Info")

    val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build())
}
```

Comment: You can simplify your question to be generic to the problem (which I think is setting multiple alarm times) and focus the title on that problem, and remove anything not needed to convey that problem.  It makes it easier to focus on just the issue, including if you state what it is "I tried to google it but I haven't found an answer yet" doesn't define what "it" means.  What technical action are you trying to take, what is the actual outcome vs. the expected outcome.  Simplify, clarify.

Comment: I've edit it. thank you

Comment: cool, I don't know enough about Android to help but hopefully, someone will come along and help!

Comment: could you vote for my quistion?

Answer (score 3):

You have to put different requestCode in pending intent, each alarm manager requires different requestCode.
in your mainActivity

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, (0..2147483647).random(), myIntent, 0)
```

Comment: When answering it would be nice to provide a practical example to help the OP.